Playwright WebView2 example tests not working in TS, does not open app
Im trying to test a WebView2 application. The app is supposed to launch with a remote debugging port which can be accessed over CDP. When I use the example code provided on: https://playwright.dev/docs/webview2 it only works when using .Net. I need it to work using TS.
Im using Win 11 Enterprise and presumably the latest Playwright.
I did not edit the playwright config or do any changes at all.
In my app I have the following:
internal Builder(WebView2 webView2)
{
    WebView2 = webView2;
    WebView2.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += (_, e) =>
    {
        if (e.IsSuccess)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("WebView2 initialized");
        }
    };
}

This writes out a line when the init is finished if I understand correctly.
In my test setup I use the following code:
public class WebView2Test : PlaywrightTest
{
    public IBrowser Browser { get; internal set; } = null!;
    public IBrowserContext Context { get; internal set; } = null!;
    public IPage Page { get; internal set; } = null!;
    private Process? _webView2Process = null;
    private string _userDataDir = null!;
    private string _executablePath = @"correctPath";

    [SetUp]
    public async Task BrowserTestInitialize()
    {
        var cdpPort = 10000 + WorkerIndex;

        Assert.IsTrue(File.Exists(_executablePath), "Make sure that the executable exists");

        _userDataDir = Path.Join(Path.GetTempPath(), $"playwright-webview2-tests/user-data-dir-{WorkerIndex}");
        if (Directory.Exists(_userDataDir))
        {
            Directory.Delete(_userDataDir, true);
        }

        _webView2Process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(_executablePath)
        {
            EnvironmentVariables =
                {
                    ["WEBVIEW2_ADDITIONAL_BROWSER_ARGUMENTS"] = $"--remote-debugging-port={cdpPort}",
                    ["WEBVIEW2_USER_DATA_FOLDER"] = _userDataDir,
                },
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        });

        while (!_webView2Process!.HasExited)
        {
            var output = await _webView2Process!.StandardOutput.ReadLineAsync();
            if (_webView2Process!.HasExited)
            {
                throw new Exception("WebView2 process exited unexpectedly");
            }
            if (output != null && output.Contains("WebView2 initialized"))
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        var cdpAddress = $"http://localhost:{cdpPort}";
        Browser = await Playwright.Chromium.ConnectOverCDPAsync(cdpAddress);
        Context = Browser.Contexts[0];
        Page = Context.Pages[0];
    }

    [TearDown]
    public async Task BrowserTestCleanup()
    {
        _webView2Process!.Kill(true);
        _webView2Process.Dispose();
        await Browser.CloseAsync();
    }
}

This correctly opens the app automatically and I can take a screenshot of it in a test. Great, .Net works.
But when I try to do exactly the same in TS, it just does NOT!
This is the TS code:
import { test as base } from '@playwright/test';
import fs from 'fs';
import os from 'os';
import path from 'path';
import childProcess from 'child_process';

const EXECUTABLE_PATH = 'correctPath'

export const test = base.extend({
  browser: async ({ playwright }, use, testInfo) => {
    const cdpPort = 10000 + testInfo.workerIndex;
    
    fs.accessSync(EXECUTABLE_PATH, fs.constants.X_OK); // Make sure that the executable exists and is executable

    const userDataDir = path.join(
        fs.realpathSync.native(os.tmpdir()),
        `playwright-webview2-tests/user-data-dir-${testInfo.workerIndex}`,
    );

    const webView2Process = childProcess.spawn(EXECUTABLE_PATH, [], {
      shell: true,
      env: {
        ...process.env,
        WEBVIEW2_ADDITIONAL_BROWSER_ARGUMENTS: `--remote-debugging-port=${cdpPort}`,
        WEBVIEW2_USER_DATA_FOLDER: userDataDir,
      }
    });

//Gets stuck on the await new Promise, App is not launched by the looks of it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    await new Promise<void>(resolve => webView2Process.stdout.on('data', data => {
      if (data.toString().includes('WebView2 initialized'))
        resolve();
    }));

    const browser = await playwright.chromium.connectOverCDP(`http://localhost:${cdpPort}`);
    await use(browser);
    await browser.close();
    childProcess.execSync(`taskkill /pid ${webView2Process.pid} /T /F`);
    fs.rmdirSync(userDataDir, { recursive: true });
  },
  context: async ({ browser }, use) => {
    const context = browser.contexts()[0];
    await use(context);
  },
  page: async ({ context }, use) => {
    const page = context.pages()[0];
    await use(page);
  },
});

export { expect } from '@playwright/test';

As you can see Im using the example code. It just does not open the App and it gets stuck on the await new Promise. i indicated it in the code.
Thank you for any help!
Szilko
